# Create plugin that makes objects from model in back-end

Tags: octobercms

I'm trying to find my way in the documents but I can't really find what I'm looking for.

My wish is to create a page in the back-end where the admin can create objects from a model with a form. These objects will be displayed on the front-end.

Is there anyone who can help me getting this started? It would be awesome if there already was a plugin that makes this work.

Comment: This is quite similar to Rainlab's blog plugin. Did you already check that out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OctoberCms provide a Builder to help you to build a plugin
https://octobercms.com/blog/post/say-hello-builder
https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-builder

This tools will help you to create tables in the database and backend forms/lists to fill the database.

Builder provides universal CMS components that you can use for displaying records from your plugins on the front-end website pages